# Same url for two pages in asp.net web routing

Tags: asp.net

I am working on web page url routing. I want two route url with equal no. parameters, same pattern and same url but different route name.
My routes are below.

```
Routes.MapPageRoute("Route1", "{parameter1}/{parameter2}", "packages.aspx");
Routes.MapPageRoute("Route2", "{parameter1}/{parameter2}", "destination.aspx", false, null, null,new RouteValueDictionary { { "isDestination", "yes"} });
```

When I call virtual path data, I am only redirecting on url that is written on top of global file.

```
 VirtualPathData vpd =RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath(null,
               "Route1",
               "parameter1", "parameter2");

VirtualPathData vpd =RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath(null,
               "Route2",
              "parameter1", "parameter2");
```

Vpd return route for Route1.
How can I construct both url for two different pages?

Comment: have you got any solution? please let me know..

Answer (score 1):

**First Option:** You use [route constraints](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-route-constraint-cs) to restrict the browser requests that match a particular route. You can use a regular expression to specify a route constraint.

**Second Option:** You can use constant parameter to distinguish between your routes which have same number & type of parameters.

Eg.:

```
Routes.MapPageRoute("Route1", "packages/{parameter1}/{parameter2}", "packages.aspx");
Routes.MapPageRoute("Route2", "destination/{parameter1}/{parameter2}", "destination.aspx", false, null, null,new RouteValueDictionary { { "isDestination", "yes"} });
```

Comment: how to solve the same problem with 4.0 non-MVC project? I have same condition same parameters but need to rediect to different page?
i have same issue! i mean to say how to decide the destination page depending on URL eg:1. routes.MapPageRoute("carriers", "{state}/{mcat}/{dcat}", "~/carriers.aspx"); 2.routes.MapPageRoute("phones", "{state}/{mcat}/{dcat}", "~/phones.aspx"); if value in URL second parameter i.e mcat=cellphone then it must redirect to carriers.aspx. and if mcat=iphone then it must redirect to phones.aspx page how to do? any idea?

Comment: @SHEKHARSHETE did you get any solution for this??