# Routing multiple pages in ASP .net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes, url-routing, asp.net-routing

I am trying to route 2 pages but its only routing the first registered one only. Here is the code:

```
 static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapPageRoute("DynamicCity", "{dCity}.aspx", "~/DynamicCity.aspx");
    routes.MapPageRoute("DynamicPage", "{Description}.aspx", "~/DynamicPage.aspx");
}
```

Why its only routing **DynamicCity**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this will help you because you didn't specify what your URL scheme is. But if all you want is to send `/DynamicCity.aspx` to the `~/DynamicCity.aspx` page and have all of your other pages routed to their own names, you could just do something like this:

```
static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapPageRoute("Page", "{pageName}.aspx", "~/{pageName}.aspx");
}
```

But then, since ASP.NET will do this anyway, I am not sure what you are expecting from .NET routing.

Normally, people use `MapPageRoute` to remove the `.aspx` extension from the URL (like shown) or to completely change the URL.

```
static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapPageRoute("Page", "{pageName}", "~/{pageName}.aspx");
}
```

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14641784/same-url-for-two-pages-in-asp-net-web-routing#14641922) for some other ideas.

Answer (score 0):

How is the routing system supposed to know the difference between two routes, when both have the same form of `{parameter}.aspx`? It can't. And since routes are evaluated in order, the first one has priority.

Comment: Cant i route 2 different sites?

Comment: @Jamil I don't even know what you would mean by "route 2 different sites".

Comment: I don't think i had asked much difficult question.

Comment: @Jamil Yes, you did. Because like I said in my last comment, I have no idea what you mean by "route 2 different sites". Simply stating it's not a difficult question doesn't explain what you mean. You need to specifically state what you're trying to accomplish.